# Exporting each land use listed in a shapefile column as a distinct shapefile

Tags: for-loop, geopandas, shapefile

I have a shapefile with a column (named "Type") that lists 10 different land use types (string). I am trying to export each specific land use type as a distinct shapefile so that I will have 10 shapefiles each of which containing data on one land use. I have written the code below, but it only exports one land use (the one that comes last alphabetically), and I am not able to figure out how to fix my code.

```py
data = gpd.read_file('G:/My Drive/The effects of land use/Final_Land_Use_-_2015.shp')

use = data.Type.unique()
for Type in use:
    gdf = data[data.Type==Type]
    gdf.to_file("Desktop/LST/{Type}.shp")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're not properly constructing the file path. You're trying to use python's string formatting, but you didn't use the "f" prefix.

```py
data = gpd.read_file('G:/My Drive/The effects of land use/Final_Land_Use_-_2015.shp')

land_uses = data["Type"].unique()
for land_use in land_uses:
    gdf = data.loc[data["Type"] == land_use]
    gdf.to_file(f"Desktop/LST/{land_uses}.shp") # <-- see the f-prefix?
```

Answer (score -1):

Modified: I completely missed deleted the data filtering part in my earlier post ,
Hope this works for you (may not be the most the efficient code, could be more simplified). I assumed the land-use column is string type
Note: i think its always best to write the spatial files in the different folder

```py
import geopandas as gpd

file_path="G:/My Drive/The effects of land use/Final_Land_Use_-_2015.shp"  
data= gpd.read(file_path)
extnsion='.shp'

use = data.Type.unique() 
for test in use:
    gdf = data[data.Type==test]
    a = file_path + test + extnsion
    gdf.to_file(a)
```

Comment: This code has several errors in it. Notably, you're not filtering the data and you're not properly constructing the file path.

Comment: appreciate the review, i completely missed out the filtering.